# Not Receiving Bounceback messages from mail() function

Tags: php, email

I'm having an issue with a PHP script where if the email is sent to a non-existent address I do not receive the bounceback message. Here's the code:

```
 $from="me@domain.com";


$fromname ="My Name";

$headers = "From: $fromname <$from>\r\n";  
$headers .= "Reply-To:  $fromname <$from>\r\n";  
$headers .= "Return-Path: $from\r\n";  

mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Maybe the recipient system simply doesn’t _send_ any?

Comment: As CBroe said, many systems don’t do this, or they only do it for a subset of IPs they deem legitimate. In the late 90s, early 2000s, spammers used to perform dictionary attacks doing this. Anything that didn’t bounce was a legitimate target for future campaigns. Similarly, there is/was reflection attacks, where Evil Alice sends to Fake Address at Important Company and lists Innocent Bob as the return, and all Bob sees is an email from Important Company, opens it, and has a virus.

Comment: I don't think its that because I've occasionally gotten a bounceback if I follow up manually on an email sent by the script.

Comment: How are you following up? With a PHP script similar to the above or with an email client potentially bound to a different message transport agent that sends common SMTP headers?

Comment: I'm following up with an email client using SMTP. do you think that changing to SMTP instead of mail() in the PHP script will solve the issue?